# How to select an element with an ID equal to a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to set an ID for every row I retrieve from the database so I can use this row later.

I've tried this setting the ID value by doing this:

But it does not work.

Here is my code:

```
            $.ajax({

            type: 'GET',
            url: "api/v1/Employees",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {

               /* var rowNumber = 0;
                var n; */
                tblBody.empty();
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {

            var row = $('<tr id="' + value.ID + '"><td>' + value.Name + 
                        '</td><td>'
                        + value.StartTime + ':00</td><td>'
                        + value.EndTime + ':00</td>');

                    $('#tblData').append(row);

                });

            }
```

Comment: Have you tried logging out `value`? Does it indeed contain an `ID`?

Comment: What is the exact error message shown? By the way, I don't see the `<tr>` tag being closed in this code

Comment: @ObsidianAge there is no error, when I try to select the row using it's ID it does not get selected hence no further operations are applied.

Comment: @AnasTiour It is ok if a <tr> does not have a closing tag.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I tried and I got undefined.

Comment: can you share what data is in `value`?

Comment: `value` was undefined it seems. What about data? Is it an array? Does the API respond with data? Could you log it please?